# SQL Server: Finding and Removing index hints in stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, regex, stored-procedures, database-performance

As we live in a World of *"delivery first"*, we now found our self with databases that are infected by **tons of index hints**.

I wrote a query that might help me find out all the `WITH (INDEX=` in the database:

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME() AS DB_NAME,
    name AS Object_Name,
    type_desc AS Object_Type,
    definition
FROM 
    sys.sql_modules 
INNER JOIN 
    sys.objects ON sys.sql_modules.object_id = sys.objects.object_id
WHERE 
    definition LIKE '%(INDEX=%';
```

but as the `definition` column is sometimes too long to read I would like to select from that column just, let's say, *30 characters before* and *30 characters after* the `WITH (INDEX=`.

[image]

How to select just that part of the string?

Basically in that column I just would like to see:

```
...INNER JOIN tblSession WITH (INDEX=indRealDateTime) ON ...
```

which is the part of the query I'm interested in. I want to see at a glance how painful is that index hint.

Comment: Once you have found the entries you can use charindex to find the location, and then substring +- 30 characters of that. But what abut where a definition contains multiple index hints? How do you intend to show them?

Comment: good question, not sure if that can be handled. Do you think this is just not possible?

Comment: What flavour of SQL are you using?

Comment: Always possible, maybe recursive query that looks starting *after* previous find, but I think you've done the hard work just finding them. From then on I'd just be opening them in your query editor and working through them methodically. Probably dangerous to try an automate as you don't know exactly where or why in the procs there might be that string.

Comment: @Nick, EXPRESS or not, does it matter?

Comment: Do you mean MS SQL Express? It changes the regex functions available...

Comment: @TomC, I know, I have done 90% of the job, but you know, sometimes you need to show an overview to your manager in order to make the balls roll and I want to show an overview of the damage. 
... and learn regular expression in SQL

Comment: @Nick, Yes, I have MS SQL EXPRESS. How can the Regex change in behalf of the flavor?

Comment: When you just tag your question `sql`, it's not clear if it's `MSSQL`, or `Oracle`, or `Postgresql` or `MySQL`, each of which has different regex functions.

Comment: Sorry @Nick, I removed SQL

Comment: First scenario, you want to show one occurrence.Get charindex  say 25,then use substring and add and substract in charindex.If you want to show multiple occurrence like what TomC said,you hv to create TVF like split string function.If you are very much confident application coding thn you can use CLR function also.It is good programming question

Comment: you can throw the data in textual format and output desire then I can give a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo Example,

```
declare @i varchar(500)='afgdfgdfgdfg dgfdgdfg dfgdfgdfg dfgdfgdfg cvxfsdfsdfdf erwererwer (index fgfdgdf weqweqweqwe dsadsads sfsfsdfd erewwerwer 6786787 35345dfsdfgsdfsdf sdfdsfsdfdf'

DECLARE @margin INT = 15 --try 15000

SELECT SUBSTRING(@i, charindex('index', @i) - @margin, charindex('index', @i) + @margin)
```

Comment: Actually @KumarHarsh, the query makes the job done: I can see the part of the query I want. But if I enlarge the column I see much more. But the query is good. Thank you

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani,this is not clear to me "But if I enlarge the column I see much more. ".Can you explain with suitable example ?do you mean multiple index in one string and you want to break them each like what tomC said.

Comment: Copy/paste your example on SSMS and run it. You see `df erwererwer (index fgfdgdf weqweqweqwe dsadsa...`. Now take the limit of the column, click on it, shift with the mouse to the right. You see now `df erwererwer (index fgfdgdf weqweqweqwe dsadsads sfsfsdfd erewwerwer 6786787 35345`. So I see 15 digits before `index` and everything after it